# PhpStorm local web server truncated output

Tags: php, localhost, phpstorm

So, here is a problem: when I launch index.php on local server a portion of code after sertain point is missing (usually around last 30% of html code, but it seems pretty random). If the php file is small, it works fine, but it struggles with 200+ lines.

When I launch http://localhost:63342/test/index.php the html ends like this:

```
...
<header class="mdl-layout__header">
    <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
        <span class="mdl-layout-title">Главная</span>
        <div class="md
```

When I launch file:///C:/test/index.php or on the external server it's fine.

HTML is correct, checked via validator.

Comment: I doubt it's line based. count bytes and see the cut-off point falls at some "obvious" number, like 4096 bytes or something. then start digging in error logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug is fixed now, according to the devs:

> 28 Sep 2015: Build with fix should be available during this week

Answer (score 1):

It's a PhpStorm issue. Please vote: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17803